# pyspark apply function on column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to run a custom function on a dataframe column. The column has a long string, which contains some Opened or Clicked information. The string format is something like this in Path column:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+               
|                                                           Path|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|/utility/tracking/opened/50DD3254-BA1D-4D0B-ADB5-6529E9C90982/0|
|/utility/tracking/tracking/ClickedUrl                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and source dataframe looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxsPW.jpg)

Now I am running following pyspark UDF to apply to "path" column which finds if "opened" or "clicked" in the column and gives me new dataframe with "path" column which has values 10 or 20 else null depending on opened clicked or else condition

```
def clickopen(x):
    if 'opened' in x.lower().split('/'):
        print(10)
    elif 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split('/'):
        print(20)
    else:
        print('null')
hunter = udf(clickopen)  
new_df = new_df.withColumn("Path", hunter("Path"))
new_df.show(n=20)
```

And the results show are null in "Path" column instead of value 10 or 20

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhB60.jpg)

Need little help with getting the integer values and please do advice if i am doing anything wrong which would be greatly appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to return the value form function not print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your main issue is that you are printing the value instead of returning it. However, even after that fix, using a `udf` here is very inefficient.

Instead, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) and [`pyspark.sql.Column.like()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.like).

Try:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

new_df = new_df.withColumn(
    "Path",
    f.when(
        f.lower(f.col("Path")).like(r"%opened%"),
        f.lit(10)
    ).when(
        f.lower(f.col("Path")).like(r"%clickedurl"),
        f.lit(20)
    )
)
```

By default, `when` will return `null` if none of the conditions match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the values from the function instead of printing them. Like this -

```
def clickopen(x):
    if 'opened' in x.lower().split('/'):
        return 10
    elif 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split('/'):
        return 20
    else:
        return None
```

I'm not sure how to return null in pySpark.